# Add php code to wp_print_scripts?

Tags: functions, jquery, block-editor, advanced-custom-fields

Is there a way to add inline php code to the editor using `wp_print_scripts`? I'm trying to find a way to display text from a php string into a value of input of a block.

Here's my code:

```
function shapeSpace_print_scripts() { 
?>
<?php $block_yt_url = 'test';?>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        let $yt_url = false;
        $(document).on( "click", '#yt_run .acf-button-group', function() {
            $(".editor-post-publish-button__button").hide();
            $(".acf-block-body div div.acf-block-fields.acf-fields div.acf-field.acf-field-text.acf-field-6260f423f1666").css({'height':'inherit','padding':'16px 20px','overflow':'inherit'});
            $(".acf-block-body div div.acf-block-fields.acf-fields div.acf-field.acf-field-text.acf-field-6260f423f1666").val(<?php echo $block_yt_url;?>);
            $('#yt_url .acf-input input').keyup(function(e) {
            if(e.keyCode == 13) {
                $yt_url = true;
            };
            if(e.keyCode == 46) {
                $yt_url = true;
            };
            if(e.keyCode == 8) {
                $yt_url = true;
            };
            checkStatus();
            });   
        });
        function checkStatus(){
            if($yt_url) {
                $(".editor-post-publish-button__button").show();
            }
        }
    });
</script>
<?php
}
add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'shapeSpace_print_scripts');
```

Comment: have you looked at `wp_add_inline_script`?

Comment: `wp_add_inline_script` doesn't.

Comment: `wp_add_inline_script` lets you enqueue an inline script so you don't have to manually hardcode the script tag yourself, but it still gets printed in the correct order, and only when the script you need it in is enqueued. The second parameter is the text that goes inside the script tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`admin_footer`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_footer/) or [`admin_head`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_head/) like below. This code only run on admin. You can also use for frontend by using [`wp_head`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_head/) or [`wp_footer`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_footer/)

```
function shapeSpace_print_scripts() { 
    $block_yt_url = 'test'; ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            let $yt_url = false;
            $(document).on( "click", '#yt_run .acf-button-group', function() {
                $(".editor-post-publish-button__button").hide();
                $(".acf-block-body div div.acf-block-fields.acf-fields div.acf-field.acf-field-text.acf-field-6260f423f1666").css({'height':'inherit','padding':'16px 20px','overflow':'inherit'});
                $(".acf-block-body div div.acf-block-fields.acf-fields div.acf-field.acf-field-text.acf-field-6260f423f1666").val(<?php echo $block_yt_url; ?>);
                $('#yt_url .acf-input input').keyup(function(e) {
                if(e.keyCode == 13) {
                    $yt_url = true;
                };
                if(e.keyCode == 46) {
                    $yt_url = true;
                };
                if(e.keyCode == 8) {
                    $yt_url = true;
                };
                checkStatus();
                });   
            });
            function checkStatus(){
                if($yt_url) {
                    $(".editor-post-publish-button__button").show();
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('admin_footer', 'shapeSpace_print_scripts');
```

If you want it will only load on specific post type editor screen you can add condition like below, I added it for page edit screen only:

```
if (isset($_GET['post'])) {
    $post_id = $_GET['post'];
    $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);
    if ($post_type !== 'page') {
        return;
    }
}
```

This above code is just for idea how you can specifically execute your JS on post type editor.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the help!